# How to calculate entropy from a set of samples?

Tags: probability, approximation, information-theory, estimation, entropy

entropy (information content) is defined as:

$$
H(X) = \sum_{i} {\mathrm{P}(x_i)\,\mathrm{I}(x_i)} = -\sum_{i} {\mathrm{P}(x_i) \log_b \mathrm{P}(x_i)}
$$

This allows to calculate the entropy of a random variable given its probability distribution.

But, what if I have a set of scalar samples and I want to calculate their entropy? In this case the probability density function is not available, but maybe there is a formula to get an approximation (as in the sample mean)? Does it have a name?

Comment: You might look for literature on "entropy estimation"... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_estimation

Answer (score 3):

The most natural (and almost trivial) way to estimate (not calculate) the probabilities is just counting: $$\hat{p_i}=\frac{n_i}{N}$$
where $p_i$ is the probabilty of symbol $i$, $\hat{p_i}$ its estimator, $n_i$ the counting of ocurrences of symbol $i$, and $n$ the total of samples. Then you plug this estimator into the entropy formula.

*However*, this might not be a fair estimator of the *entropy rate* of your source, because it does not take into account the dependencies between succesive symbols. It only makes sense if the source emits independent symbols - or if you are only interested in the *marginal* entropies (and provided that your source is stationary - ergodic, actually).

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the samples are not discrete: they are bivariate real values (coordinates)

Comment: Then you shouldn't refer to that definition of entropy, that's for discrete variables